# Cygwin - spell or ispell command not found

Tags: cygwin

Hey there! So I'm just reading this book on using UNIX and Linux (which I'm loving!), but I'm working on Cygwin cause I don't have a Linux-based OS installed.  I tried using the command spell and ispell, but non of them are found.  I searched my main Cygwin folders, and there are some ELC files names spell and ispell, but no command related to them or anything.  How do I restore those commands? TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install aspell (it is in the "Text" package) and you will also get the spell and ispell commands installed as part of the package.  ispell is a "compatibility script" for aspell (for those of us who came to love ispell, I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

It's not installed by default, but there's a package available.

Run the setup.exe you downloaded from cygwin.org, click through until you see the list of packages, and then you can find ispell listed there. You can select it and tell it to install it and it'll then download and install it for you automatically. A word of warning: it may take a bit of experimentation until you can figure out setup.exe's really awful GUI.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I check the Setup Packages, and apparently spell nor ispell exist!!! There is a aspell, though.  I tried using that command, but apparently it uses another type of input format than spell.  Gotta read on that now lol XD

Comment: Huh. I stand corrected. I'm not very surprised, though --- Cygwin is hateful in so many ways...